# videoEmbeddable flag is not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I want to filter videos that can be embedded. I am using youtube python library for searching videos and setting the **videoEmbeddable** flag as true in my search method but it does not work as I am still getting video ids that are not embeddable and hence are not playable in my mobile app.

My code for doing this query is :

```
search_response = youtube.search().list(
q=music,
part="id,snippet",
maxResults=10,
videoEmbeddable='true'
type='video'
).execute()
```

I am also setting the **videoSyndicated** parameter to true so that only videos that are playable outside youtube but even that param does not work. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1.Call the above api for a webview

2.Try to play the generated video

3.Some videos doesnot play and throw an exception

Expected output:
The videos return should be embeddable only and should play in webview

Actual results:
Some of the videos are not embeddable and does not play even in web version of youtube embeddable player.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug for this on the [gdata issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6346) but it hasn't been addressed yet. I'd recommend starring the issue so you can be notified of any updates.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
But I also raised the issue myself
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7342&thanks=7342&ts=1435006085
but I do not know how much time will they take to reply   :(